# Reasoning of a declined flag [self-improvement purpose]

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755404/scan-line-fill-opengl-glut-algorithm-in-c) (first question) is about implementing Scanline algorithm using OpenGL. One user could not understand a portion of the code and asked a [second follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250955/c-opengl-scan-line-algorithm)

As far I know, if anything related to a question needs support, it should be in comment section of that question. According to this, the second question should be asked as a comment of the first question. Isn't it?

I raised a flag about it and moderator declined me.

#### Note:

Most of the time we know the wrong information and be declined. Its go on and on as we do not try to know the actual reason of being declined. So, in this case, I might be wrong, but I need the reason for future improvement.

My flag:

[image]

Comment: In the *later question*, he did not asked about any explanation of the algorithm. He just ask why those two arrays are taken and about the array size! "What are the `re[500]` and `le[500]` arrays? And why 500?" -- does it indicate to give 'plain English explanation of the algorithm'? @kenwhite

Comment: The question in it's previous form was a very poor quality question. Thanks to your flag, a moderator found it, and fixed it. Good Job! The explanation in your flag was correct, but, making it a comment on the original question is not the correct action to take as it is a legitimate question that should be a question, not a comment. I suspect it was declined because the action you suggested was incorrect. though, it does look like the flag was helpful in that it resulted in a cleaned up question... dunno.

Comment: So, having such type of silly question referring to another question is allowed as an independent question? another thing is, what should be asked in the comment section? (this questions are for my future improvement) @KevinB

Comment: Comments are for clarification, generally in the direction of improving a question or an answer. Further questions can be asked in comments, but, they're very likely to be ignored there, and aren't very helpful to other people who may have the same question because comments cannot be searched.

Comment: I do think it's kind of "silly" for the question to have been asked as a separate question, but, i'm not a C++ dev so i don't know how significant the question actually is, so i can't really judge the usefulness of the question. but, being "silly", or, simple, basic, easy, etc. doesn't make it invalid or off topic.

Comment: Excuse me, I could not get you, please help. I meant the second question as *later question*. How [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250955/c-opengl-scan-line-algorithm) question could be an answer? @KenWhite

Comment: However, It is a thing for learning to me. Till today, I thought comments are for being clarified. I did not know that "Clarification related to another question could be asked as a separate question." Thanks. @KevinB

Comment: I have edited the question now, in terms of **first** and **second** question. Try to clarify me now. Again sorry. @KenWhite

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comments can be used to request clarifications of an answer (after which the answer should usually be edited), but we also encourage posting related questions and linking back. In fact, this is one of the stock comments used in the low quality post queue:

> If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the Ask Question button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

The user in question did not have enough reputation to post a comment, so posting a new question was their only viable option.

---

(Aside: what would you expect a moderator to do, given your flag? We can't convert a question to a comment on another question.)

Comment: That's the point, I got it now. "The user in question did not have enough reputation to post a comment". and actually I thought the question should be closed as it is very silly. Thanks, Everything is clear to me now.